# Authenticate users with both username and email

Tags: django, authentication, django-views, django-users

I have extendted the `UserCreationForm` with email and other fields, so that I could authenticate a user with both its username and email.

forms.py:

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email',)
```

views.py:

```
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    elif:
        user = auth.authenticate(email=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid_login')
```

html:

```
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}

    <label for="name">Email or Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">

    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
</form>
```

In the views I tried giving both the `username` and `email` as input from the form as `name`, and check to see if username and password authenticate. If not then check whether email and password authenticate. But its not working. How do I solve this problem? Please kindly help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an authentication backend: here is mine:

```
class EmailAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Email Authentication Backend

    Allows a user to sign in using an email/password pair, then check
    a username/password pair if email failed
    """

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        """ Authenticate a user based on email address as the user name. """
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        """ Get a User object from the user_id. """
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then in your settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('MyApp.backends.EmailAuthBackend',)
```

then create a custom view the uses the authenticate function.

Comment: Will you please kindly elaborate more. Where do I need to keep the `authentication` backend?

Comment: @Kakar you can create backends.py in the MyApp folder ...! Is there any other doubts ?

Comment: @Raja Do I need to import anything in the backends.py?

Comment: Ok had to add `from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend` and
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: @Raja Oh bdw, will it have security issues?

Comment: should not have a "security issue"... assuming you use HTTPS to connect to the site.